# How to sort MergeCursor?

Tags: android, listview, cursor

The task is to combine data from 2 different tables with similar columns, sorted by one column . 
Seems like MergeCursor might help, but have no idea how to sort items.

The only solutions I see now is converting manually to ArrayAdapter, or do sneaky JOINs (not sure yet its possible)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MergeCursor` does not offer sorting.

> The only solutions I see now is converting manually to ArrayAdapter, or do sneaky JOINs (not sure yet its possible)

I have no idea what the latter is. If you want to stick with the `Cursor` interface, you can build yourself a `MatrixCursor`. Or, you can try to create your own `CursorWrapper` that maintains the sort order and rewrites all position-related calls.

Comment: Thx for answer. The solution that worked is rawQuery with UNION ALL of several selections.

Comment: Somebody tried to implement something like this at [SortCursor.java](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/com/android/internal/database/SortCursor.java.shtml) but probably not made public due to performance issues.

Comment: @paiNie pls explain how did you managed to implement sorted merging?