# How to represent 2 cursors as 1 sorted cursor?

Tags: android, merge, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I have 2 different sets of data, each of them use its own `ContentProvider`. Querying to them I can get 2 different cursors. Those 2 cursors has 2 different primary keys, but there's one and the same field (`DATE`) which I can use for ordering (other fields are different).

My goal is to have one final merged `Cursor` which will be sorted by those `DATE` field. I have investigated `MergeCursor` but it doesn't fit to me, since it returns merged/concatenated (but not sorted `Cursor`).

Any ideas, clues?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719525/how-to-sort-mergecursor

Comment: Not sure that this is a duplicate. Since in my case I don't have direct access to database tables. I do have only cursors through respective content providers. In my case it's SMS and MMS tables. I need to have one single cursor sorted by date for a given `thread_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this class from AOSP repository: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.4.4_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/database/SortCursor.java

There is a performance warning at the beginning of the class but if you don't have 10K or 100K records it might be fine.

Comment: @hans-kratz I hate to be that guy but how would I go about changing this to be DESC order instead of ASC

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but I had a lot of problems on getting it to sort data properly. In case anyone else have the same problems, I made a separate question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379301/how-does-the-sortcursor-from-the-aosp-repository-sort-its-values