# Unable to get both SMS and MMS with query mms-sms/conversations?simple=true

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, telephony

So I'm building an SMS/MMS app and I want to get all the SMS and MMS in a conversation in one cursor.

I have to query "content//mms-sms/conversations?simple=true because (from what I've gathered) I'm using a Samsung S4 to test and the device won't let me access the "content//mms-sms/conversations" or "content//mms-sms/conversations/#" where the # is the thread_id. I have access to the SMS content provider and the MMS provider individually.

My question is how do I combine the cursors from both of them OR is there something I am missing completely to do this.. I have been exhaustively searching and haven't found anything helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do a query on both the SMS and the MMS tables and then merge them using this SortCursor that I found here:

the source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-.4.4_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/database/SortCursor.java

the stackoverflow:
[How to represent 2 cursors as 1 sorted cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448614/how-to-represent-2-cursors-as-1-sorted-cursor)

There are "problems" with performance which is why android hasn't made it public; however, this seems to only be a problem when you have 10K+ rows (which I don't have)

I also made sure to do the work of loading the two cursors and loading the sortedCursor in an asynctask.