# Query to ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI doesn't consider all contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm developing a messaging application and need a list of contacts with search-as-you-type capability.
I used Contacts.CONTENT_URI to get list of all contacts and Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI to get list filtered by name.
All seems to work fine, until some testers reported that they can't find some of their contacts using search feature but can see them when viewing whole list. As I'v mentioned above, different URIs are used in these cases.

Here is the code, which performing query to contacts ContentProvider:

```
private Cursor getContactsCursorByQuery(ContactsQuery query) {
        String orderBy = null;
        if (query != null) {
            switch (query.getSortOrder()) {
                case NAME_ASCENDING: {
                    orderBy = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
                    break;
                }
                case NAME_DESCENDING: {
                    orderBy = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE DESC";
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    LOG.warn("Unsupported sort order " + query.getSortOrder());
                }
            }
        }

        ContentResolver contentResolver = CONTENT_RESOLVER;
        Cursor cur;
        Uri uri;
        if (query != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(query.getName())) {
            // In search mode
            uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI.buildUpon()
                    .appendEncodedPath(Uri.encode(query.getName()))
                    .build();
        } else {
            uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        }
        cur = contentResolver.query(uri,
                CONTACTS_LIST_PROJECTION,
                null,
                null,
                orderBy);
        LOG.debug("Got cursor by query " + (query != null ? query.toString() : "{}"));
        return cur;
    }
```

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong I studied sources of contacts application from AOSP and found references to ContactsContract.Directory. After some further investigations I'm ended up with such solution:

- query each directory's CONTENT_FILTER_URI;

- merge result cursors and sort them using slightly modified solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448614/how-to-represent-2-cursors-as-1-sorted-cursor);

```
private Cursor getContactsCursorByQuery(ContactsQuery query) {
        String orderBy = null;
        if (query != null) {
            switch (query.getSortOrder()) {
                case NAME_ASCENDING: {
                    orderBy = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
                    break;
                }
                case NAME_DESCENDING: {
                    orderBy = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE DESC";
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    LOG.warn("Unsupported sort order " + query.getSortOrder());
                }
            }
        }

        ContentResolver contentResolver = CONTENT_RESOLVER;
        Cursor cur;
        Uri uri;
        if (query != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(query.getName())) {
            // In search mode
            uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI.buildUpon()
                    .appendEncodedPath(Uri.encode(query.getName()))
                    .build();
            Directory[] directories = getDirectories();
            LOG.debug("Contacts directories: " + Arrays.toString(directories));
            List<Cursor> cursors = new ArrayList<Cursor>();
            for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
                if (directories[i].getId() != ContactsContract.Directory.LOCAL_INVISIBLE) {
                    Uri queryUri = uri.buildUpon()
                            .appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY,
                                    String.valueOf(directories[i].getId()))
                            .build();
                    LOG.debug("Contacts of directory Uri: " + queryUri.toString());
                    Cursor tempCur;
                    tempCur = contentResolver.query(queryUri,
                            CONTACTS_LIST_PROJECTION,
                            null,
                            null,
                            orderBy);
                    if (tempCur != null) {
                        cursors.add(tempCur);
                    }
                }
            }
            Cursor[] cursorArray = new Cursor[cursors.size()];
            cursors.toArray(cursorArray);
            cur = new ContactsSortCursor(cursorArray, query.getSortOrder());
        } else {
            uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            cur = contentResolver.query(uri,
                    CONTACTS_LIST_PROJECTION,
                    null,
                    null,
                    orderBy);
        }
        LOG.debug("Got cursor by query " + (query != null ? query.toString() : "{}"));
        return cur;
    }
```

But, unfortunately, issue still persists and I left with no ideas how to fix it. Need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity in question title. Just edited it. As you can see from code snippets I'm using exactly ContactsContract.Contacts.